# Mode line overflow/interference with Spaceline

Tags: mode-line, powerline, spaceline

I am using Spaceline with the following configuration:

```
(use-package spaceline-config
  :config
  (setq-default
    mode-line-format '("%e" (:eval (spaceline-ml-main)))
    powerline-default-separator 'wave
    spaceline-flycheck-bullet "❖ %s")
  (spaceline-install
    'main
    '((evil-state)
      (version-control :when active)
      (projectile-root :when active)
      (buffer-id))
    '((remote-host :when active)
      ((flycheck-error flycheck-warning flycheck-info) :when active)
      (major-mode :face highlight-face)
      (("L" line column) :separator ":"))))
```

However there is some interference between the mode-line and Spaceline, causing an overflow effect. I've tried using Powerline, patching fonts and fiddling with the powerline height, but that doesn't seem to help.

[image: spaceline overflow]

This is on the Macports version of Emacs 25 on macOS. Font is Fira Mono.

Answer (score 1):

Powerline (and thus spaceline) inherits font properties from the fonts mode-line and mode-line-inactive. At one point these fonts must have added an underline, visible in the image by this ugly grey line.

The solution `(setq x-underline-at-descent-line t)` proposed before fixes the issue by moving the underline "out of the way". Unfortunately, it places all your underlines at the descent line which is ugly.

I suggest to instead solve this issue by `customize-face RET mode-line` and `customize-face RET mode-line-inactive` and in each dialog setting `:underline nil`

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the problem for me:

```
(setq x-underline-at-descent-line t)
```

Comment: You might want to explain how/why this fixes the problem. You might want to show what `C-h v` presents for this variable.

Comment: Fixed it for me as well. I don't think anybody wants to try to understand how the position of the underline breaks the spaceline.